# GTX 750ti Massive FPS Drop In Games After OC

Tags: graphics-card, performance

Firstly say that I have tried to search the web but couldn't exactly find a similar issue.

My specs:

- PC Model: Acer mc605 (I've upgraded the videocard)
- CPU: Intel i5 3350p 3.10GHz
- RAM: 6GB (can't find brand)
- Graphics: ASUS nVidia GTX 750ti OC 2gb
- OS: Windows 10
- Monitor: 1920x1080

I played some games and i would like to overclock the videocard a bit to get more fps, so the videocard had a program included (GPU Tweak).

Before overclocking I got around 40fps in games, when I enabled "Gaming mode" in GPU Tweak and go back to the game I get 60fps for 3 seconds and then the game crashes. When i start the game again i get 20fps.

It doesnt matter which profile I enable in GPU Tweaks or which game I play, I always get fewer fps.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers seems to make it go back to normal fps.

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Your power supply probably doesn't have enough juice to give the video card what it needs to perform according to your parameters, and I can't imagine your cooling system will be able to do much for the added head overclocking brings.
I'd recommend leaving overclocking until you have a PC you've assembled yourself for this explicit purpose.

Comment: Going from 40 FPS to 60 FPS would likely be a very significant overclock and there is a good chance that it is causing your graphics card to overheat and drop into a thermal throttling mode. The time taken to reinstall the drivers probably allows it to cool down sufficiently to work normally again. Overclocking is something that shouldn't be done lightly, it has the potential to do permanent damage. Small overclocks are probably okay, large ones should only be done when you have established that a) the card can take it (tested) b) that there is sufficient cooling, and c) your PSU is sufficient

Comment: Thanks seagull and mokubai for ur comments i will just leave it.

Comment: Does the video card have an external power connector or does it draw all of its juice from the PCI-E slot it's connected to? I have an EVGA 750ti OC which pulls all juice from its slot and it's a great card, but you cannot OC it because it cannot get enough juice to do the job well.